# Collection of open intervals $(a,b) \ a,b\in \mathbb{Q}$ is a basis for euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$

Tags: general-topology

I'm not sure if this question hasn't already been asked here, but I couldn't find it.

I'm currently studying topology and I'm reading a book which unfortunately has no answers to the exercises.

Here it one:

Let $\mathcal{B}$ be the collection of all intervals $(a,b)$, $ \ a<b, \ \ a,b \in \mathbb{Q}$.

Prove that $\mathcal{B}$  is a basis for euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$.

I know that if $a,b \in \mathbb{R}$ then the collection of such intervals would be a basis for euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$, because a subset of $\mathbb{R}$ is open iff it is a union of open intervals.

I also know that $\mathcal{B}$  is a basis for a topology on $X$ iff

(1) $X= \bigcup_{B \in \mathcal{B}}$ B

(2) $\forall B_1, B_2 \in  \mathcal{B} \ : \ B_1 \cap B_2$ is a union of elements of  $\mathcal{B}$.

But using this wouldn't lead anywhere because it only shows that $\mathcal{B}$  is a basis for a topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and not the euclidean one.

How can I use to prove the above lemma? Could you help me with that?

Thanks.

How can this question asked 3 years ago be a duplicate of a question asked 3 days ago?
There seems to be something wrong with the chronology...

Comment: You need to show that for an open set $U$ in $\mathbb R$ and a point $x\in U$ there is an interval with rational end points $(a,b)$ such that $x\in(a,b)\subseteq U$. This implies that the collection $\mathcal B$ generates a topology finer than the euclidean.

Comment: So I just need to use the fact that the set of rational numbers is dense, is that right?

Comment: Yes, you are using the fact that $\mathbb Q$ is dense in $\mathbb R$.

Comment: But you still need to show that it is a basis (points (1) & (2) in your post)

Comment: Right, I think (2) is quite obvious. What about (1)?

Comment: (1) is what I'd call "really obvious." $$\mathbb R =\cup_{n\in\mathbb N}[-n,n]$$

Comment: Ok, but intersection of two intervals with rational endpoints is an interval with rational endpoints or an empty set (empty union).Either way, it belongs to the basis.

Comment: Yes, (1) is really obvious, but it also follows from what I wrote in my first comment, since every $x$ is contained in the intervall $(x-\epsilon,x+\epsilon)$.

Comment: And if you have shown that some collection of sets generates a topology finer than a given topology, then (1) is automatic. Here "generates" means taking unions of finite intersections. Any collection generates a topology, and is then called a "subbase" for the generated topology. You get a base for this topology by considering finite intersections of all sets in the collection.

Comment: You can explicitly express an interval $(x,y)$ where $x$ and $y$ are real as a (nested) union of (countably many) intervals with rational endpoints.

Comment: @AndréNicolas: Do you use the decimal expansion of $x$ and $y$ for the countable nested union?

Comment: @StefanH.: You can. Or you can just assert (density of the rationals) that for any $n$ there exist rationals $a_n,b_n$ such that $x\lt a_n\lt b_n\lt y)$ such that $a_n-x\lt 1/n$ and $y-b_n\lt 1/n$. Then $(x,y)=\cup(a_n,b_n)$.